# Check if values are contained within a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Unfortunately I was unable to find a function that achieved the following:

Inputs:

- test: Tensor of values that may exist within target
- target: Tensor of values

Outputs:

- output: Tensor of boolean, same shape as test. `output[i] = targets.contains(test[i])`

---

Put plainly: I need to test whether the elements of a Tensor are contained within another Tensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer updated 2020-03-23 to use setdiff.

You want to use [`tf.sets.difference`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sets/difference).

Given two tensors `test` and `target`,

```
not_in_target = tf.sets.difference(test, target)
```

`not_in_target` will contain the items from test that *are not* in the target.  If you want instead to find the ones that *are* in the target, you can set diff it again:

```
tests_in_target = tf.listdiff(test, not_in_target)
```

Which then contains items from `test` that were successfully found in the `target` tensor.

Comment: listdiff() has been discontinued, can you suggest another method to do the same?

Comment: setdiff1d is the same as listdiff.

Comment: I think it's a deprecated method!

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the post to use the latest API call.